# Compare 3 or more date ranges in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to compare 3 or more date ranges in Google Analytics?

It's obvious how to compare 2 ranges.  It would be great to see additional ranges - seeing the data of 6 months overlaid - seeing 3 years compared on the same chart etc.

Comment: There is no such functionality built into Google Analytics.

Comment: Ok, thanks Stephen.  I was hoping there was some trick.  There is so much advanced and custom functionality.  You would think this would be possible... oh well.

Answer (score 2):

While there is no way to do this in Google Analytics, there are a few easy steps you can take if you are just looking to visualize your data on more then two ranges:

1) Export Month/Week data from GA to Google Sheets

2) Setup all 3 ranges in columns on one sheet

3) Publish the sheet and copy the sheet id number

4) Use [HighCarts Clou](https://cloud.highcharts.com/)d to import your data.

This whole process takes about 10 minutes. Or if you use highcharts API it would make it even easier after the initial set up. I have number of reports that I generate for myself. Here is a quick snapshot of one:

[image]